# Routing Error uninitialized constant Devise::Controllers::InternalHelpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I have a rails 3.1 app. I am trying to access the sign in page. I previously had this working and all of a sudden I am getting the error that I have given in the title. I have also tried googling and looking at other stackoverflow questions and was wondering is there anyone out there who may have experienced this same similar problem? And if so how do you overcome.

I have checked my terminal and found that I recieve the following:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Devise::Controllers::InternalHelpers):
  app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:3:in `<class:SessionsController>'
  app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

It points that the error is in `app/controllers` however I cannot see this folder in the app folder as I installed devise as a gem. How could I possibly access the controllers.

Comment: Which version of Devise are you using?

Comment: The latest one which should be 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself it appears there was a compatible issue so I used devise 1.5.3

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634605/uninitialized-constant-devisecontrollersinternalhelpers for a possible solution.